# Philips TAH5205 bluetooth not working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, sound, bluetooth

I am running  Ubuntu 20.04 Kernel version 5.14.0-1044-oem #49-Ubuntu SMP Mon x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux on Dell Latitude 5520. I have a Philips TAH5205 Wireless headset which I can not connect via bluetooth. It did detect once, but never worked since then. However, I do see a **LE-Philips TAH5205** in the bluetooth devices list. If I try to pair it I am prompted to verify a Pin!

I can connect other bluetooth devices though, like the keyboard I am typing this on.

Has anyone seen specific issue with this Philips model?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks and Regards,
J

Answer (score 0):

I have a similiar model, you probably need to activate the pairing mode.

- Turn off the headphones
- Turn them back on and wait for 5 secs
- Connect from device's list

Hope it helps :)